# How can i take picture to call a number

Tags: applications

I think there was option in some app, dont remember what it was. But you could take picture to call it.

I want to simply take picture of a number and call the number. Photo need not to be saved.

It'd be huge benefit to me.

I think it should be possible i'm not talking about hand written numbers, i'm talking about numbers on screen or billboard etc.

Comment: Google Goggles may do the trick. It can be used to read text from pictures and much more (including reading QR codes).

Comment: Any news on this in year 2021? (iPhone now supports this natively, with iOS 15)

Answer (score 2):

Google Goggles will do what you are asking. It does an analysis of any taken picture (without saving it to your phone). The results of the analysis will depend upon your picture (for example, if you take a picture of a famous painting it will tell you what the painting is).

In your case if you take a picture of a phone number, it will highlight the number in the picture allowing you to select and dial it.

Comment: does it require data from carrier.

Comment: It does require data; which it can get from either your carrier or from being connected to a WiFi network.

Comment: i've 100mb limit which gets full by breathing i think.

Answer (score -1):

Use a QR code. Scan the QR code with your camera, and make sure that a phone number is set as the content within the code. You should then get an option to open the number (as usual) with your preferred dialer.

Comment: i said i want to use number from billboard or screen.