# Dial number with camera/picture

Tags: calls, camera

Is there a way so I can quickly take a picture, highlights the number and I click it so it calls the number? Or I click take picture, and call.

So it just takes the photo, process it, extract number, calls it?

Comment: **Optical Character Recognition (OCR)** is the term you need to Google in relation to Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i take picture to call a number](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/how-can-i-take-picture-to-call-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think processing an image and extracting the number and calling it a better idea. the OCR processing will not be 100% all the time and it may call a different number at-times.

A QR-code is more reliable than image processing and can be used for this if you dont want to type the number.

A [QRcode Generator site](http://blog.qr4.nl/QR-Code-Telephone.aspx) to call to a specific number directly by scanning the code after generating it. Haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Google Goggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil), It reads all the readable stuff (barcode, words, numbers).

P.S. it will read numbers for you, then you need to copy and dial that by yourself (but it can Google that number for you).